# Why don't Break points work with Python in PyCharm / Intellij using Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, pycharm

Is there a reason why debug and break points don't work with Python in PyCharm / Intellij using Google App Engine?

Or if they do, how do you configure it to make them work?

Comment: Update: It turns out break points DO work - the problem was weirdly hidden. It turns out I have run the program without later stopping it. When I exited PyCharm and started it again, the debugger worked. No other settings required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if it's a remote instance of Google App Engine or not.  Perhaps it's a setup issue:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration.html

Comment: It's a local instance.
It could well be a setup issue - I hope it is because it will mean it's actually possible. But I can't find any guidance on what needs to be done to configure it. That links seems to just describe what the debug configuration is. 
It's currently all on default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up PyCharm properly?

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/google-app-engine.html